# CI default controller loading by user level

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have login system with sessions and users levels 1 and 2,
need to do when someone login, example: when user with level 1 load default controller "home_user" and if login with level 2, load default controller "home_admin".

What is the best way to do dynamic controller? or example, i think just set default controller in routes main.php

in main file check if by level

```
if ($this->session->userdata('level') == 1)
{
   require_once('home_user.php');
} else {
   require_once('home_admin.php');
}
```

But what is the rational way?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->session->userdata('level') == 1)
{
   redirect('home_user'); // This controller will have user logic and views
} else {
   redirect('home_admin'); // This controller will have admin logic and views
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.